# Rails AplicationController trouble

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have it in my ApplicationController

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  $banner = Banner.first
  $template = Template.first
end
```

and in my _myfile.html.erb

```
<%= $template.mainpage_benefits.html_safe %>
```

My terminal has next error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `html_safe' for nil:NilClass
```

I don't met this practice before($template = Template.first). Please, explain me, how i can fix it

Comment: try to use `raw` method

Comment: check why dont you use `@template` instead of  `$template`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct your view with:

```
<%= $template.mainpage_benefits ? $template.mainpage_benefits.html_safe : '' %>
```

As someone else pointed out in comments, usually it's better to use instance vars ( `@template` ) in these situations.

Comment: it is  a version code works in production and i can't  delete or upgrade this code. Why in production this code is work, but in my local machine is not. I wanna start on localhost this project without any changes )))

Comment: $template - is nill class for me. Problem here ))

Comment: Try executing `rails console` - then: `Template.first` - from the error it seems like `templates` table is empty

Comment: In rails console works good: Template.first.mainpage_benefits.html_safe

=> "just for develop mode(this my example)" . But when I load page it's not working.. It can't found it(nill) I think, route to aplication controller can't be found

Comment: project has active admin and i found this code : 
    ActiveAdmin.register Template do
        2  
        3  # See permitted parameters documentation:
        .
        14      update! do |format|
        15        format.html {
       16:        $template.reload
        17         redirect_to :back
        18         }

Comment: And finally I understood this point. I must go to the active_admin and edit and update template without changes.And all works good. Thanks for your attention